# Two conflicting definitions of "$\omega$-accumulation point"

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

I came across two different definitions of **$\omega$-accumulation point**.

1. From Steven A. Gaal's *Point Set Topology*, [p.136](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lgg7BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA136) [emphasis added]

   > Call a point $x \in X$ an **$\omega$-accumulation point** of $S$ if $N_x \cap S$ is *uncountable* for every neighbourhood $N_x$.
2. From John L. Kelley's *General Topology*, [pg.137](https://books.google.com/books?id=-goleb9Ov3oC&pg=PA137) [some emphasis added]

   > A point $x$ is an **$\omega$-accumulation point** of a set $A$ iff each neighborhood of $x$ contains *infinitely many* points of $A$.

The second definition is precisely the known definition of an **accumulation point**. Then what's the point of adding the letter $\omega$ to it?

And these definitions are very different from each other. When the definition is not given which should one assume? And why are there two completely different definitions of the same term?

Comment: Def. 1 is usually the definition for a _condensation point_. Def. 2 is the standard definition of an $\omega$-accumulation point. In $T_1$-spaces, every limit point (accumulation point) of a set is an $\omega$-accumulation point, but in non-$T_1$ spaces, the concepts are different. [See also.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point)